# How can I test the arguments a Rust program passes to another program?

Tags: testing, rust, command-line-interface

I’m writing tests for a command-line tool which lets you specify a pager. I want to test that the tool passes the right arguments. I figured I’d write a single-line binary that checks the arguments and exits with a non-zero status code (plus some STDERR output) if they’re not right, then put a test under `tests/` that runs this binary and checks its output, which I can run as usual using `cargo test`. This setup works if I place the binary under `src/bin`, but then the test binary is also installed when using `cargo install`.

When I placed the `.rs` file for the binary under `tests/`, it simply wasn’t compiled into a binary.

I tried putting it under a crate in the same workspace, but then it’s not built when running `cargo build` in the root crate… unless I specify it as a default member, in which case we’re back to it being installed when using `cargo install`.

For example, given code like this:

```
use std::process::Command;

fn run_pager(pager: &str) {
    let output = Command::new(&pager)
        .env("SOME_VAR", "FOO")
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed to run pager");

    // do something with the command
}
```

And a stub `test-binary.rs` that looks like this:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(env::var("SOME_VAR").unwrap(), "FOO");

    // …produce output with special markers…
}
```

How can I write `tests/passes-correct-args.rs`:

```
#[test]
fn runs_pager_with_args() {
    // pass `test-binary` to `run_pager` and verify output
}
```

Comment: Do you absolutely need a Rust program to be invoked to check the inputs, or would a simple script (bash/python) suffice?

Comment: This is not the indented way for `tests/` tests. Please see the links i provided. "*Tests in your src files should be unit tests, and tests in tests/ should be integration-style tests*"

Comment: @MatthieuM., as long as it’s portable, I’m fine with using anything. It needs to work on Windows, Linux, and OS X that I know of. I wouldn’t want to add an external dependency like Python, though—that’s a lot for this one test. I figured Rust would be the one thing I could assume the user has.

Comment: @hellow, could you explain how this is incorrect and what the correct method would be?

Comment: @hellow: Isn't checking how a call to another program works *exactly* an integration test?

Answer (score 0):

Make your test binary a new Cargo project under `src` and then reference it in your main projects as a dev dependency using a relative path.

`[dev-dependencies]
test_binary = { path = "src/test_binary", version = "0.1" }`

Comment: This sounds promising, but if I make it a binary crate then the binary is never built during compilation or testing of the main crate, and with a library crate I only get a `.d` file in `target/debug/`. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Keep it a binary crate but add a `lib.rs` file to it. Does it build now?

Comment: Looks like it might not be possible https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2267. I guess you could try invoking the compiler from your tests.

Comment: Blast… I was hoping to avoid that, since I have no knowledge of the compiler, but I guess I don’t have a choice in this case. (I tried adding a `lib.rs` to a binary crate before I commented. It just ignores the binary.)